# free() causing stack overflow

Tags: c++, stack-overflow

I am trying to develop an application with **Visual Studio C++**  using some communication `DLLs` .
In one of the DLLs, I have a stack overflow exception.

I have two functions, one receives packet, and another function which do some operations on the packets.

```
static EEcpError RxMessage(unsigned char SrcAddr, unsigned char SrcPort, unsigned char DestAddr, unsigned char DestPort, unsigned char* pMessage, unsigned long MessageLength)
{
    EEcpError Error = ERROR_MAX;
    TEcpChannel* Ch = NULL;
    TDevlinkMessage* RxMsg = NULL;

    // Check the packet is sent to an existing port
    if (DestPort < UC_ECP_CHANNEL_NB)
    {
        Ch = &tEcpChannel[DestPort];
        RxMsg = &Ch->tRxMsgFifo.tDevlinkMessage[Ch->tRxMsgFifo.ucWrIdx];

        // Check the packet is not empty
        if ((0UL != MessageLength)
            && (NULL != pMessage))
        {
            if (NULL == RxMsg->pucDataBuffer)
            {
                // Copy the packet
                RxMsg->SrcAddr = SrcAddr;
                RxMsg->SrcPort = SrcPort;
                RxMsg->DestAddr =DestAddr;
                RxMsg->DestPort = DestPort;
                RxMsg->ulDataBufferSize = MessageLength;
                RxMsg->pucDataBuffer = (unsigned char*)malloc(RxMsg->ulDataBufferSize);
                if (NULL != RxMsg->pucDataBuffer)
                {
                    memcpy(RxMsg->pucDataBuffer, pMessage, RxMsg->ulDataBufferSize);

                    // Prepare for next message
                    if ((UC_ECP_FIFO_DEPTH - 1) <= Ch->tRxMsgFifo.ucWrIdx)
                    {
                        Ch->tRxMsgFifo.ucWrIdx = 0U;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Ch->tRxMsgFifo.ucWrIdx += 1U;
                    }

                    // Synchronize the application
                    if (0 != OS_MbxPost(Ch->hEcpMbx))
                    {
                        Error = ERROR_NONE;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Error = ERROR_WINDOWS;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Error = ERROR_WINDOWS;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // That should never happen. In case it happens, that means the FIFO
                // is full. Either the FIFO size should be increased, or the listening thread 
                // does no more process the messages.
                // In that case, the last received message is lost (until the messages are processed, or forever...)
                Error = ERROR_FIFO_FULL;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Error = ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Trash the packet, nothing else to do
        Error = ERROR_NONE;
    }

    return Error;
}

static EEcpError ProcessNextRxMsg(unsigned char Port, unsigned char* SrcAddr, unsigned char* SrcPort, unsigned char* DestAddr, unsigned char* Packet, unsigned long* PacketSize)
{
    EEcpError Error = ERROR_MAX;
    TEcpChannel* Ch = &tEcpChannel[Port];
    TDevlinkMessage* RxMsg = &Ch->tRxMsgFifo.tDevlinkMessage[Ch->tRxMsgFifo.ucRdIdx];

    if (NULL != RxMsg->pucDataBuffer)
    {
        *SrcAddr = RxMsg->ucSrcAddr;
        *SrcPort = RxMsg->ucSrcPort;
        *DestAddr = RxMsg->ucDestAddr;
        *PacketSize = RxMsg->ulDataBufferSize;
        memcpy(Packet, RxMsg->pucDataBuffer, RxMsg->ulDataBufferSize);

        // Cleanup the processed message
        free(RxMsg->pucDataBuffer);   // <= Exception stack overflow after 40 min
        RxMsg->pucDataBuffer = NULL;
        RxMsg->ulDataBufferSize = 0UL;
        RxMsg->ucSrcAddr = 0U;
        RxMsg->ucSrcPort = 0U;
        RxMsg->ucDestAddr = 0U;
        RxMsg->ucDestPort = 0U;

        // Prepare for next message
        if ((UC_ECP_FIFO_DEPTH - 1) <= Ch->tRxMsgFifo.ucRdIdx)
        {
            Ch->tRxMsgFifo.ucRdIdx = 0U;
        }
        else
        {
            Ch->tRxMsgFifo.ucRdIdx += 1U;
        }

        Error =ERROR_NONE;
    }
    else
    {
        Error = ERROR_NULL_POINTER;
    }

    return Error;
}
```

The problem occur after 40 min, during all this time I receive a lot of packets, and everything is going well.
After 40 min, the stack overflow exception occur on the free. 
I don't know what is going wrong.

Can anyone help me please ?

Thank you.

Comment: The problem is most likely unrelated to the specific call of the `free` - it happens some time earlier than that. The problem could happen, for example, if you overwrite "bookkeeping" info of the block being freed. Run with valgrind to see the actual memory error.

Comment: Should questions about stackoverflow be here or on meta?

Comment: @user93353 hahaha nice one (I hope)

Comment: Try [enabling CodeGuard](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE/en/Using_CodeGuard) and see if it finds anything.

Answer (score 2):

A few suggestions:

1. The line

   ```
    memcpy(Packet, RxMsg->pucDataBuffer, RxMsg->ulDataBufferSize);
   ```

   is slightly suspect as it occurs just before the `free()` call which crashes. How is `Packet` allocated and how are you making sure a buffer overflow does not occur here?
2. If this is an asynchronous / multi-threaded program do you have the necessary locks to prevent data from being written/read at the same time?
3. Best bet if you still need to find the issue is to run a tool like Valgrind to help diagnose and narrow down memory issues more precisely. As *dasblinklight* mentions in the comments the issue most likely originates somewhere else and merely happens to show up at the `free()` call.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Regarding your comment uesp, ProcessNextRxMsg function is called in another DLL in a Thread. Here is how Packet is allocated: unsigned char Packet[ US_ECP_MESSAGE_LENGTH_MAX ]; And then, in a While loop in a the thread: memset( Packet, 0, US_ECP_MESSAGE_LENGTH_MAX );// Prepare for next packet. I notice something strange: the size of Packet at the creation in the caller DLL is 20240, but when I check the size of Packet in the second DLL (where the problem is) the value is 4. Someone knows why this is happening ?

Comment: I assume you check somewhere that `RxMsg->ulDataBufferSize` never exceeds `US_ECP_MESSAGE_LENGTH_MAX`? It's impossible to say what is changing the packet size but a buffer overflow could potentially cause it. Double-check that all buffers are being allocated the correct size and writes to them cannot overflow.

Comment: I don't check that `RxMsg->ulDataBufferSize` never exceeds `US_ECP_MESSAGE_LENGTH_MAX`. When `memcpy` is called, `RxMsg->ulDataBufferSize`'s value is 8 and Packet size is 4. It's weird that the size of Packet change. The caller DLL is developed in **C++ Builder**, and the DLL where there is the problem is developed in **Visual Studio**. All I do is calling a function with Packet size 20240 in the DLL developed in **C++ builder**, but when I check the size in called function in **Visual Studio**, the Packet size is 4. And as you said, this could potentially cause a buffer overflow